# CppDepend.Console.exe closes very quickly

Tags: windows-console, code-metrics, cppdepend

I'm using CppDepend and I need it to be running from the command line. So, I'm using CppDepend.Console.exe, my problem is that it opens for 1 seconds and closes immediately! I don't even get to type anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CppDepend.Console.exe must be launched  from the command line. So you have to launc Cmd terminal and after execute from it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, that's what I fixed it, I have to launch the cmd from the CppDepend folder and then put the full path of the project.